# Barplot shifted in R

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have the folowing:

```
km1 <- c(0.037, 0.066,  0.048,  0.11,   0.105,  0.113,  0.05)
km2 <- c(0.037, 0.062,  0.048,  0.102,  0.106,  0.116,  0.048)
km3 <- c(0.032, 0.05,   0.05,   0.1,    0.106,  0.118,  0.042)
km4 <- c(0.031, 0.052,  0.052,  0.086,  0.09,   0.114,  0.04)
km5 <- c(0.037, 0.074,  0.046,  0.12,   0.114,  0.132,  0.044)
km6 <- c(0.037, 0.062,  0.046,  0.1,    0.106,  0.118,  0.042)
age <- c(30,45,60,75,90,105,120)

mydata <- matrix(c(km1, km2, km3, km4, km5, km6), nrow = 6, ncol = 7, byrow = TRUE)

barplot(mydata, beside = TRUE,
        col = c("yellow","blue","indianred","red2","green","purple"),
        legend.text = rownames(age),
        xlab = "age", ylab="GR",
        ylim=c(0.000, 0.200),
        xlim=c(30,120),
        axes=FALSE, las=2)
box()
axis(side=1, at=seq(30,120, by=15), cex.axis=0.8, tck=0.02)
axis(side=2, at=seq(0.000, 0.200, by=0.025), cex.axis=0.8, tck=0.02, las=1)
```

I need to have each coloumn set on exact date. But when I'm trying to use this code, the image moves.

Here's the result:

[image]

What's exactly wrong with that?

I want to achieve this result:
[image]

Comment: It's not completely clear to me what are you trying to achieve... could you please post an image of your desired result ? Anyway, the culprit is `xlim`; barplot calculates the position of the columns automatically (and returns it invisibly), forcing it between 30-120 you're shifting the plot...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick hack: do not set `xlim` and put the age labels exactly where you want...

```
res <- barplot(mydata, beside = TRUE,
    col = c("yellow","blue","indianred","red2","green","purple"),
    xlab = "age", ylab="GR",
    ylim = c(0.000, 0.200),
    axes = FALSE, las=2)
box()

axis(side=1, at = colMeans(res), labels=age, cex.axis=0.8, tck=0.02)
axis(side=2, at=seq(0.000, 0.200, by=0.025), cex.axis=0.8, tck=0.02, las=1)
```

I think the result looks like what you would like:

[image]

A solution based on `ggplot2`:

```
require(reshape2)
require(ggplot2)

mydata2 <- data.frame(km1=km1, km2=km2, km3=km3, 
                      km4=km4, km5=km5, km6=km6, age=age)
datm <- melt(mydata2, value.name="km", variable.name="class", id.vars="age")
ggplot(datm, aes(x = factor(age), y = km, fill=class)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position="dodge", color="black")
```

The result looks quite nice:

[image]

---

EDIT1: add horizontal lines

```
res <- barplot(mydata, beside = TRUE,
    col = c("yellow","blue","indianred","red2","green","purple"),
    xlab = "age", ylab="GR",
    ylim = c(0.000, 0.200),
    axes = FALSE, las=2)
box()
abline(h=(seq(0.000,0.200,0.025)), col="lightgray", lty="dotted")

axis(side=1, at = colMeans(res), labels=age, cex.axis=0.8, tck=0.02)
axis(side=2, at=seq(0.000, 0.200, by=0.025), cex.axis=0.8, tck=0.02, las=1)
```

---

EDIT2: set colors manually (not recommanded)

```
ggplot(datm, aes(x = factor(age), y = km, fill=class)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position="dodge", color="black") + 
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("yellow","blue","indianred","red2","green","purple"))
```

Comment: You shouldn't calculate axis x with `4+7*(0:6)` since barplot calculation may differ. You should use the result value of barplot which indicates the x-coordinates for each column...

Comment: Thank you so much! It's exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: I strongly recommend to first store the result of barplot (e.g. `res <- barplot(...)`), then instead of `4+7*(0:6)` use `at=colmeans(res)`.

Comment: Also, `rownames(age)` is wrong, should be `rownames(mydata)` (of course you should set some values first)

Comment: And last but not least, the problem was NOT `axes=FALSE` but `xlim=c(30,120)`... @VincentGuillemot you should change your answer

Comment: The second version looks quite nice. But I've an error: "Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (42): x, y, fill"
How could I use it?

Comment: I updated the code a few times because I realized there were some bugs: does the error appear with the newest version?

Comment: It works! Thank you. However, it's a bit complicated to me to understand the code completely. For example, where exactly I can set the color of columns and x-y axis names.

Comment: and one more.. In the first case. I wish to use argument `panel.first = abline(h=(seq(0.000,0.200,0.025)), col="lightgray", lty="dotted")`. When I put it into the `plot()` code, it also moves this gray lines somewhere down. But they should continue y axis.

Comment: Gettong used to `ggplot2` is not easy, but I think it is worth the extra work. I would not recommend changing the default color palette, although it is possible to change it quite easily. For the horizontal lines, just add them outside of the `barplot` command. (see edits in the answer)